# Grails / Spring Security - Registration email does not unlock account

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I am running a site grails site with spring security where users register for an account, then use their email address to log in.  In testing, I find when I create an account, I get the verification email, but clicking on the link does not unlock the account.   I actually have to log in as admin and go into the spring security user management UI and manually unlock the account.   This is just recently an issue (when we switched from users having a username to having users log in with just their email address).  Any ideas why the "registration" link would not automatically unlock an account?

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. Please do some research first and provide more details about your problem.

Comment: Make sure that the links that travels on the email goes to a controller that handles that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at the RegisterController source in Spring Security: (https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ui/RegisterController.groovy#L113 ) I found that during validation, the code attempts to look up the user by username, when it should be looking up the user by email.   Since this can be overloaded, I simply rewrote the offending portion.